# How to redirect to same page after form submission

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I am working on a plugin where a new page template is created on plugin activation. The template has a form for user input.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="question"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_question">
</form>
```

Value is properly stored in following way:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit_question' ] ) ) {
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array( 'question' => $question,
               'created_at' => $created_on
        ),
        array( '%s', '%s' )
    );
}
```

The issue is, if the page is reloaded after form submission, its restoring the values again. How can I clear the values after submission? Or redirect properly? I tried some solutions (e.g. `wp_redirect` ) but not getting any result. Please help.

Comment: Rather than a reload consider using AJAX and then the values remain unless you remove them.
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to `exit;` after the `wp_redirect()`?

“Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;”

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Answer (score 0):

A common use of PHP_SELF variable is in the action field of the  tag. The action field of the FORM instructs where to submit the form data when the user presses the “submit” button. It is common to have the same PHP page as the handler for the form as well.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " method="post">
    <textarea name="question"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_question">
</form>
```